# What's going on with my PowerShell window title?

Tags: powershell

So, when I launch "Windows PowerShell" from the Start menu, the title reads...

> Windows PowerShell

I then pin it to the taskbar and close the window. If I now launch it from the taskbar, it reads...

> Windows PowerShell (2)

What is going on and how do I get my normal title back?

Comment: It would be polite to accept [TheMadTechnician's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1199496/20240) as correct; that answer certainly worked for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The items pinned to your taskbar are stored in two places. First there is a shortcut stored for the item, which can be located here:

```
%AppData%\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar
```

But that's not all of it. Things that you pin to the taskbar are indeed saved there as a shortcut, but order and what not go beyond simple files, so Windows also saves info on this in the registry here:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Taskband
```

in the `Favorites` binary value. If you hunt through there you'll find reference to the shortcuts in the folder, as well as other things like the Windows App Store and stuff that don't necessarily have a shortcut. So, how to fix this? Ug, that's a hard one because you not only have to fix the shortcut name in the folder, you also have to change the binary value for it found in the registry. It's probably simpler to just live with it, or change the title as part of your profile.

```
$Host.ui.rawui.WindowTitle = 'My awesome PowerShell window!'
```

Comment: Best way to fix this, remove all entries and repin to taskbar.

Comment: Easier said that done in some cases. If the registry still thinks that there should be the original non-numbered entry but the file doesn't exist I have seen it re-pin things with the number on them.

Comment: Yeah, thats why you remove the registry entry and the file.

Comment: I would hesitate to do that, and I'm pretty comfortable with the registry. How do you get back things like the Task View button, or the Store button? These buttons do not have an associated shortcut to just re-pin.

Comment: Task View is a windows feature. Just right-click and enable it. The store is an icon that you find in your start menu and can be pinned from there.

Answer (score 0):

Well in my case the title of PS window stays the same after such action. I guess that there might be a bug in the powershell version that you received from windows, due to which you've encountered this.

Any ways the title of the powershell window can again be set with the following command:

```
$host.ui.RawUI.WindowTitle = 'Some Name'
```

You can also use the following command in the Command prompt(cmd) or RunAs Dialog Box for getting the PowerShell Window with desired Title in the traditional CMD styled window.

```
cmd /k PowerShell -NoExit -Command "& {$host.ui.RawUI.WindowTitle = 'Powershell'}"
```

P.S: Its like traditional CMD with PowerShell features and Syntax Highlighting.